# Fire event after expand/collapse tree

Tags: java, tree, swt

I need to fire event resize after collapse and expand. When I try to do that using SWT.Collapse and SWT.Expand, there is no changes on tree because its fire before its happen. Is there any way to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Display.asyncExec` to schedule a `Runnable` in the `SWT.Collapse/Expand` listener. The `Runnable` will not run until the current `Tree` operation is complete.